# What iOS or Android PDF readers have a "go back" functionality?

Tags: pdf

I am looking for a PDF reader that can handle large PDFs efficiently... but, importantly, allow the user to go back to a previous page once they follow a link.  It seems to me this feature should be standard, but I cannot seem to find it on any of the big PDF readers. Maybe I am missing it, but I have looked in Acrobat, Xodo, and Apple iBooks.